# Operator '=' chaining in C# - surely this test should pass?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, operators

I was just writing a property setter and had a brain-wave about why we don't have to `return` the result of a `set` when a property might be involved in operator `=` chaining, i.e:

```
var a = (b.c = d);
```

(I've added the brackets for clarity - but it makes no difference in practise)

I started thinking - where does the C# compiler derive the value that is assigned to `a` in the above example?

Logic says that it should be from the result of the `(b.c = d)` operation but since that's implemented with a `void set_blah(value)` method it can't be.

So the only other options are:

- Re-read `b.c` after the assignment and use that value
- Re-use `d`
- ***Edit** (since answered and comments from Eric) - there's a third option, which is what C# does: use the value written to `b.c` after any conversions have taken place*

Now, to my mind, the correct reading of the above line of code is

> set `a` to the result of setting `b.c` to `d`

I think that's a reasonable reading of the code - so I thought I'd test whether that is indeed what happens with a slightly contrived test - but ask yourself if you think it should pass or fail:

```
public class TestClass
{
  private bool _invertedBoolean;
  public bool InvertedBoolean
  {
    get
    {
      return _invertedBoolean;
    }
    set
    {
      //don't ask me why you would with a boolean,
      //but consider rounding on currency values, or
      //properties which clone their input value instead
      //of taking the reference.
      _invertedBoolean = !value;
    }
  }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ExampleTest()
{
  var t = new TestClass();
  bool result;
  result = (t.InvertedBoolean = true);
  Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

This test *fails*.

Closer examination of the IL that is generated for the code shows that the `true` value is loaded on to the stack, cloned with a `dup` command and then both are popped off in two successive assignments.

This technique works perfectly for fields, but to me seems terribly naive for properties where each is actually a method call where the actual final property value is not guaranteed to be the input value.

Now I know many people hate nested assignments etc etc, but the fact is the language lets you do them and so they should work as expected.

Perhaps I'm being really thick but to me this suggests an incorrect implementation of this pattern by the compiler (.Net 4 btw).  But then is my expectation/reading of the code incorrect?

Comment: I think the result of a property set is `value`. Obviously it can lead to strange behavior if your setter does something which a setter shouldn't do as in your example

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple.aspx In short:  "the result of the simple assignment operator is the value that was assigned to the left-hand side"

Comment: @Henrik - ah interesting blog by Eric there.  I can't say I agree with it, but then I wasn't on the C# team and never will be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The result of an assignment `x = {expr}` is ***defined*** as *the value evaluated from {expr}*.

> ### §14.14.1 Simple assignment (ECMA334 v4)
>
> ...
>   The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to
>   the left operand. The result has the  same type as the left operand,
>   and is always classified as a value.
>   ...

And note that the *value assigned* is the ***value already evaluated*** from `d`. Hence the implementation here is:

```
var tmp = (TypeOfC)d;
b.c = tmp;
a = tmp;
```

although I would also expect with optimisations enabled it will use the [`dup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.dup.aspx) instruction rather than a local variable.

Comment: you're right, yes, it's in the language spec and has been since day one.  It doesn't sit right with me - I think that test should pass- but whether it's right is a whole different question too subjective to be asked on SO and probably too irrelevant in the grand scheme of things!

Comment: actually - in that case this could have interesting side effects if `a` and `b.c` are of a type that is different to `d` and which defines a conversion operator. It would actually fire the conversion twice, rather than copy the result. I really don't like that - especially in cases of reference types.

Comment: @Andras: I'm not following your train of thought here. If you have "a = b.c = d" then d must be converted to the type of c. The value of (b.c = d) is the value that is assigned to b.c. If that value needs to be converted to the type of "a" then it will be. How is that not sensible? For example, suppose "a" is long, "c" is int and "d" is short. d must be converted to int, and then the result of that conversion must be converted to long. Two conversions are unavoidable if there are two target types!

Comment: @Eric, thanks for popping in :) I agree with that, but consider if `typeof(a)` and `typeof(c)` are the same but different to `typeof(d)` - e.g a reference type that defines a conversion from type of `d`. As it is now the operation requires two conversions (two identical conversions from `typeof(d)` to `typeof(a & c)`; whereas using the result of `b.c=d` (i.e. the resulting value of `c`) would trigger only one, and the resulting reference to be copied to `a`.  In this case, the second seems more natural.  I can see the argument for the way that it has been implemented, however.

Comment: @Andras: I am still not following you. Suppose a and c are of type C, and d is of type D. d must be converted to C to assign d to b.c.  The value of the assignment is the value that was assigned, and *the value that was assigned is of type C*. Why then would there be a second conversion from D to C?  We already have a value of type C in hand.

Comment: @Andras: I think you are misunderstanding. The value of the assignment (b.c = d) is not the value of d and it is not the value of b.c -- in part because b.c might not have a value; it could be a write-only property. **The value of the assignment is the value that was assigned to b.c**

Comment: @Eric - Ah okay - I see what you mean - I should have examined the IL for that scenario before pre-judging what it does; the conversion is done first and the result is `dup`ed on the stack then used for both assignments.  Fair enough :)

Comment: I feel like the wording of the spec is a little confusing on this one. Given the deep discussion here, I can see that "the value assigned to the left operand" means "the value assigned *by this operation* to the left operand," but had I read it without thinking, I could easily have interpreted it to simply mean "the value of the left operand." I understand that that's not the case, and I understand why it *can't* and *shouldn't* be the case, but I feel like the wording could use some clarification.

Answer (score 16):

I find it interesting that your expectation is that the *crazy* assignment -- that is, assigning two different values because one of them is an extremely weird property with unusual behaviour -- is the *desirable* state of affairs.

As you've deduced, we do everything in our power to avoid that state. That is a *good* thing. When you say "x = y = z" then if at all possible we should guarantee that x and y end up assigned the same value -- that of z --  even if y is some crazy thing that doesn't hold the value you give it. "x = y = z" should logically be like "y = z, x = z", except that z is only evaluated once. y doesn't come into the matter at all when assigning to x; why should it?

Also, of course when doing "x = y = z" we cannot consistently "reuse" y because y might be a *write only* property. What if there is no getter to read the value from?

Also, I note that you say "this works for fields" -- not if the field is volatile it doesn't. You have no guarantee whatsoever that the value you assigned is the value that the field takes on if it is a volatile field. You have no guarantee that the value you read from a volatile field in the past is the value of the field now.

For more thoughts on this subject, see my article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple.aspx

Comment: Good point about volatiles there; and I understand what you say about the crazy assignment; I also understand the desire for the language to provide some form of guarantee.  However the assignment doesn't always have to be crazy (as I say it could be rounding a double, cloning an input reference, or a converted reference).  Also, to my mind, `a = (b.c = d)` raising a compiler error if `b.c` is write only makes sense - I can't read `c` so I can't use it to assign to `a`. That said; I'm sure lots of thought went into this decision and I suppose it is 'the best fit' and most consistent.

Comment: @Andras: your belief seems to stem from the idea that "a = c = d" is intended to act like "c = d, a = c". It is actually intended to act like "c = d, a = d". The roles of "c" and "a" are that they are *to be written*; nothing here *reads* "c".

Comment: yes you're right - I expected C# to do `c=d, a=c` because, to me that's what `a=c=d` actually says - if `a=c` is an expression, then it returns its result, and it's result, to me, is `a` and some languages would agree; but C# says its result is the value written to `a` (neatly avoiding the need to re-read the written variable/property). Ultimately a language is free to specify what each and every statement and expression means within it's own scope and C# has every right to do that in this case - if that's the C# rule then I'm happy to work with it :)

Comment: @Andras: I can see why you would think that, but doing that does lead to some oddities. For example, suppose b.c is a read-write property of type string. Suppose you see `string x = b.c = null; if (x==null) { ` wouldn't it be surprising if the conditional were *not* hit?  It sure looks like x ought to always be assigned null there. But if b.c is implemented as `get { return _c; } set { _c = value ?? ""}` and we did it your way, then x would be an empty string, not null!

Comment: yup absolutely agree, it would be odd, and if the language did enable this kind of thing then I as a developer would have to be very careful if I were ever going to be returning a value that wasn't necessarily written (notwithstanding my stubborn boolean example); unless the caller expected it.  I would *like* to be able to have that freedom, but it's equally cool that I can't.  I appreciate your time on this question :)

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator is documented to return the result of evaluating its second operand (in this case, `b`). It doesn't matter that it also assigns this value to its first operand, and this assignment is done by calling a method that returns `void`.

The spec says:

> **14.14.1 Simple assignment**
>
> The = operator is called the simple assignment operator. In a simple assignment, the right operand shall
>   be  an expression of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type
>   of the left operand. The operation assigns the  value of the right
>   operand to the variable, property, or indexer element given by the
>   left operand.  The result of a simple assignment expression is the
>   value assigned to the left operand. The result has the  same type as
>   the left operand, and is always classified as a value.

So actually what happens is:

1. `d` is evaluated (let's call the value produced `val`)
2. the result is assigned to `b.c`
3. the assignment operator's result is `val`
4. `a` is assigned the value `val`
5. the second assignment operator's result is also `val` (but since the whole expression ends here, it goes unused)

Comment: When you say "(in this case, `b`)" don't you actually mean "in this case, `d`"?